# My query doesn't give any results

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

What seems to be the problems?

I got right results from each select query, so I put all the queries together,

But combining them, ms access doesn't give me the result.

Technically speaking, it is still working to finish this query.

Can you give any tips for me?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT t.* 
      FROM MyTable AS t 
      WHERE t.ID not In (SELECT TOP 8 id     
                         FROM  (SELECT * 
                                FROM MyTable 
                                WHERE subject = "Math" Or subject ="Science")     
                         WHERE StudentID = t.StudentID    
                         ORDER BY TestScore asc, id asc) AS a
WHERE a.ID In (SELECT TOP 4 id
               FROM (SELECT tt.* 
                     FROM MyTable AS tt 
                     WHERE tt.ID not In (SELECT TOP 8 id     
                                         FROM  (SELECT *
                                                FROM MyTable
                                                WHERE subject = "Math" Or subject ="Science")
                                         WHERE StudentID = t.StudentID    
                                         ORDER BY TestScore asc, id asc) AS b
               WHERE b.StudentID = a.StudentID 
               ORDER BY b.TestScore asc, b.id asc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding one query at a time? to rule out the problem? its much easier to break the problem down and solving it from there.